# Do I need to have a database

Tags: java, database, message-queue

Here is my use case:

1. Input data is present in a Message Queue.
2. Application needs to read input data and present it to end user via UI.
3. End user will to review the data and decide accordingly.
4. Once decision is made, data can be discarded. (irrespective of yes/no).

I have two approaches in my mind to develop this application,

**Approach-1:**

1. Consume data from queue,
2. Persist it into a Database.
3. Make the frontend talk to Database to retrieve data when user logs in.

**Approach-2:**

1. Consume the data from queue.
2. Directly have it fed to the user with out persisting.

But my only concern with Approach-2 is, lets say a user logs in and consumes all the data. He may/may not be able to review all the records.So,all the records may not be reviewed.

Is there anyway a MQ consumer can persist data?

Comment: Which message-queue did you plan on using?

Comment: I m trying to use Activemq

Answer (score 0):

1. What if the message queue fails? Is the queue durable? You can use durable queue, so if the user can't connect to the queue, the messages won't be missed. The user retrieves them when he's able to connect to the message queue.
2. You can make another service that logs all the user's actions on the input data. At least it will be easier to understand and investigate differrent issues.